# Cannot see statement text in Sql Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

When I perform a Sql Profiler trace (SQL Profiler from SQL Server 2014). I can not see the statement text in the bottom pane as I am used to, as I highlight each line.

I am not sure if this is a change in SQL Server for 2014 or some problem in my setup.

I can see the statement text by expanding the TextData column, but the only way I can copy it appears to be by choosing Edit | Copy Cell, which is quite clunky.

Does anyone know if there is a way to restore the viewing of the SQL text that we used to have in older versions of SQL Server?

Comment: Do you see the bottom pane at all? Or is it not present?

Comment: Yes, I have the bottom pane, but it is empty -it doesn't change as I click from line to line

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found two 'solutions'.

1. Start the profiler from SSMS - Go to the Tools Menu and select SQL Server Profiler.
2. Run profiler as Administrator.